# Unity IAP and export compliance for App Store and Google Play

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, encryption, google-play, app-store

I want to release my first app to Google Play and App Store. I have a question about Export Compliance issue. Since I didn't even know this is needed I am struggling.

I made the game using Unity, and I am using Unity IAP for in-game purchases. Since I didn't add any encryption on my own into the game and answers on Unity Forums are mixed, could someone please help me with an answer to those 2 questions in app store and do I need to do anything additional?

I can't post images so I am copying the text.

First question:

> Export Compliance Information.
>   Does your app use encryption? Select Yes even if your app only uses the standard encryption within Apple’s operating system.

If the answer to first is yes, this is the second one

> Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?
>
> Make sure that your app meets the criteria of the exemption listed below. You are responsible for the proper classification of your product. Incorrectly classifying your app may lead to you being in violation of U.S. export laws and could make you subject to penalties, including your app being removed from the App Store.
>
> You can select Yes for this question if the encryption of your app is:
>   (a) Specially designed for medical end-use
>   (b) Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection
>   (c) Limited to authentication, digital signature, or the decryption of data or files
>   (d) Specially designed and limited for banking use or “money transactions”; or
>   (e) Limited to “fixed” data compression or coding techniques
>
> You can also select Yes if your app meets the descriptions provided in Note 4 for Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I posted a question to Unity Forums as well and found out they are using SSL encryption and more. You can read more here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-iap-and-export-compliance.742898/

Answer (score -1):

You will select "No". Unity IAP does not use encryption.

There is an another question about advertisement. If you have Ads in your app, you will select yes. And tick the "serve advertisement within the app" (something like this). If you do not have ads in your app, basically select "No" for it too.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this because I've seen an answer on some forums that it might use it. Also, how do they then check if payment has been made without encryption.

Also, if I select no, I get this notification.
"If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS, you are required to submit a year-end self classification report to the US government."

But as I understand I do not have to do this if I'm using Unity IAP.

Also, Unity Ads don't use encryption right? What about Google Play services or Game Center?

Comment: Let me put it this way, I've been using all those services you listed for a long time. I've always selected "No". There is no problem so far :)

Comment: Or you just haven't been caught xD But in all seriousness, I'll wait a little bit in case anyone else will have some input, otherwise I'll just use "no" as well. Thanks :)